# Why is keygen done in ionic?

Tags: html, ionic-framework

After I have created an unsigned app in ionic, I have to create a key. Why it is so? What is the need of keygen and signing the app.
Why an app doesn't work without key?
Please, explain the concept behind this mechanism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A key generator (key-gen) is a computer program that generates a product licensing key, such as a serial number, necessary to activate for use of a software application.

According to Oracle, In order to be able to create a digital signature, you need a private key. (Its corresponding public key will be needed in order to verify the authenticity of the signature.)

It can be seen as software validation and licensing process, so that we can cross-check the developer of the app.
Apart from keygen, there are various building and signing process for the release. They are as follows:

1. Add Android platform support in your app if you have not done so. Inside your app root folder, type in terminal: `$ ionic platform add android`
2. Create your digital signed key `$ keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore -alias alias_name -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000` Follow the on screen instruction to type in your password and information. Please save this key in a safe location. You will need it again when you sign a new build and release an update.
3. Build an release version of your app `$ ionic build --release android` It will generate an android-release-unsigned.apk file under your platform/android/build/output/apk path. Copy the apk file into your app root folder so you do not need to type in the path.
4. Sign your release build apk. `$ jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore my-release-key.keystore android-release-unsigned.apk alias_name`.

These processes are required to install the apk file over our device smoothly. And also, these are the mandatory steps to be followed before uploading our app for Google Play Store.
I hope, it would be sufficiently enough for you.

Comment: Yeah, welcome. I am happy that it solved your query.